# Partition Table: Master Boot Record (MBR)

Tags: memory, linux, hard-drive

I would like to understand an article about the Master Boot Record

My problem is on the bit 2 hexa bit calculation

### It said :

- Have 64-byte partition table
- The 64-byte partition table has four 16-byte entries

### The 16-byte entries are divises like that:

- 1 bit  : is bootable
- 3 bits : CHS (the first sector)
- 1 bit  : The partition type
- 3 bits : CHS (the last sector)
- 4 bits : LBA (the first sector)
- 4 bits : Number of sector in the partition

### I get the hexadecimal representation of these 64 bits

```
[root@echidna ~]# dd if=/dev/sda bs=510 count=1 2>/dev/null|tail -c 64 |hexdump -C
```

### The output :

```
00000000  80 01 01 00 07 fe ff ff  3f 00 00 00 98 66 b9 08  |........?....f..|
00000010  00 fe ff ff 83 fe ff ff  61 5c 39 09 21 c7 17 00  |........a\9.!...|
00000020  00 fe ff ff 05 fe ff ff  82 23 51 09 85 ab 68 66  |.........#Q...hf|
00000030  00 fe ff ff 82 fe ff ff  d7 66 b9 08 8a f5 7f 00  |.........f......|
```

... Look like I just get my 4 16 bits entry ...

### Just look at the first one :

```
00000000  80 01 01 00 07 fe ff ff  3f 00 00 00 98 66 b9 08  |........?....f..|
```

bit 1 : 80

bit 2 : 01

bit 3 : 01

bit 4 : 00

etc...

If all of them are 1 bit, how a value
like "fe" for the 6th one can be there. The decimal representation of "fe" is 254 and its way larger that 1 bit!

Comment: seems you mixup bits and bytes

Comment: Should be migrated to superuser or stackoverflow.

Comment: Yep I just realise it :S my fault , sorry